# replace std::mutex queue with lock less transfer of data

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic

Currently i try to understand the semantics of std::atomic and especially the memory_order_acquire/memory_order_release.

I read this blog post
http://preshing.com/20140709/the-purpose-of-memory_order_consume-in-cpp11/
but i am not sure if the pattern i tried to implement in my sample is correct.

The purpose is to replace a classic std::mutex locked "pass data from one thread to a queue", "Grab with an other thread from the queue" with a lockless Operation.

My idea is that the receiver reads from the payload when the guard is 1. The Sender writes to the payload when the guard is 0.

I run this sample lots of cycles and the assert never got triggered. I know, it is difficult to impossible to prove there is no fault with running lots of cycles...

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>

std::atomic<int> Guard(0);
int payload = 0;

void receiver()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        int g;
        while ((g = Guard.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) == 0);
        assert(payload == 42);
        payload = 0;
        Guard.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
    }
}

void sender()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        int g;
        while ((g = Guard.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) != 0);
        assert(payload == 0);
        payload = 42;
        Guard.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::thread t1(receiver);
        std::thread t2(sender);

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not lock-free.

This might come as a surprise, since you did not use `std::mutex` anywhere, but that alone is not enough to give you lock-freedom. The problem is that you still send your threads spin-waiting if the atomic `Guard` does not have the expected value. And they might very well spin forever, unless another thread sets them free.

This is the very definition of a (spin-)lock. You just implemented it yourself using atomics, instead of using a pre-made lock from a library.

In order to make it [truly lock-free](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/non_blocking_lock_free_and_wait_free.html), you will need a significantly more complex implementation.

> For a data structure to qualify as lock-free, if any thread performing
>   an operation on the data structure is suspended at any point during
>   that operation then the other threads accessing the data structure
>   must still be able to complete their tasks. This is the fundamental
>   restriction which distinguishes it from non-blocking data structures
>   that use spin-locks or other busy-wait mechanisms.

This is not the case for your implementation. You require that you always get a `sender` thread followed by a `receiver` thread. If the `receiver` comes first, it will be blocked until a `sender` completes. If that does not happen, the `receiver` will be blocked forever, happily burning CPU time while busy-waiting. Likewise, if a second `sender` starts after the first, it will be blocked until a `receiver` has finished executing and reset the guard.

Multiple senders and receivers running at the same time will lead to races, although that might have been an intentional restriction here.

Designing proper lock-free algorithms is orders of magnitude harder than using locks. It's so easy to mess up that it's almost ridiculous. If you are still 100% determined to give it a try, make sure you have a rock-solid understanding of atomics and get yourself a pile of literature on the topic. Then take a look at existing implementations like [Boost.Lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/lockfree.html). There be dragons! Don't say I didn't warn you.